# Google App Scripts : Javascript code inside the HTML file not functioning

Tags: google-apps-script, google-plus

I have been trying to write a small Google App Script which has the Google+ badge as shown [here](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/badge/). For this I have a plain HTML file where I have included the HTML as shown on that page. The HTML page is as follows :

```
 <html>
<body>
 <div class="g-plus" data-href="{Page-Link}" data-rel="publisher"></div>
  
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    alert("Added Badge!");
  })();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The result is a blank page. There is no badge added to the page . I assume this is because the javascript function is not being run( I added an alert and there wasnt any pop-up ).I am not able to figure out why the function is not being run.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The `data-href` attribute must be your Google profile URL.

Comment: I have placed the link to the Google profile there. But it still does not show the badge.

Comment: Looking at the html source that's served, it appears that the plusone.gs library does not survive the caja compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I'm not too experienced with Javascript so I'm guessing here. I've programmed in coffeescript a while ago and its compiler automatically wraps the generated code in an anonimous function just as in your code. This function is called so:

```
(function() {//...}).call(this);
```

Maybe this works.

Alternatively you might want to move the alert test above the badge generation. This would show if the javascript is run at all. Maybe the error lies in your badge creation code.

My final idea would be to name your function and register it as a callback on body.onload . It's always a good idea to let the browser load the page before accessing the dom